# Update operation not working in MVC5 with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

***Please Help***

> This is how i'm updating....

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
      public ActionResult Edit(Students model)
       {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DbAccess db = new DbAccess())
            {

              var ID=db.students.Find(model.id);
              db.Entry(ID).State = EntityState.Modified;
              //ID.name = model.name;
              //ID.address = model.address;
              //ID.age = model.age;
              //ID.email = model.email;
              //ID.isActive = model.isActive;

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

> In the above code when i update separately than it works well but when i use db.Entry(...)...... than it doesn't work for me and it also not shows any error

Answer (score 0):

just replace this:

```
db.Entry(ID).State = EntityState.Modified;
              //ID.name = model.name;
              //ID.address = model.address;
              //ID.age = model.age;
              //ID.email = model.email;
              //ID.isActive = model.isActive;
```

with:

```
UpdateModel(ID);
```

and you'll be fine;

In order for your method to work, you need to do like this:

```
db.Students .Attach(ID);

var entry = db.Entry(ID);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

entry.Property(x => x.name).IsModified = true;
entry.Property(x => x.address).IsModified = true;   
....
db.SaveChanges();
```

Basically you need to attach the updated model then to tell to the context, which props are modified.

I have in my repository, another method which I use in some situations, when the update is not done in the controller, the method is:

```
 public void Update(TEntity newEntity)
 {
     var oldEntity = Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(newEntity.Id);

     Context.Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(newEntity); 
 }
```

In this method, the `newEntity` is comming from the view, and the `oldEntity` is from the context.

`UpdateModel` can be used only in controllers, when I call the update outside of the controller, I use the above method. I prefer this methods because I do not need to explicitly tell which props are been modified. When you have a form with 10 props, and user is updating only 3 or 4, you need a lot of logic to determine which were modified.

PS - my entities are all implementing `IEntityId`, which is an interface with common properties, like Id, UpdateDate, InsertDate ..., this is why I can call `newEntity.Id`

Comment: you can read more about `UpdateModel` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.updatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Thank you @Lucian its really work for me but can you please explain why db.Entry(ID).State=EntityState.Modified;  not working?? And these both methods are same??  thnxx

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `var ID=db.students.Find(model.id);`

You don't need to use
`db.Entry(ID).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Because when you do `Find` you have real object of your dbContext, when you make changes on it(except on it primary key of course), your `SaveChanges` will detect it and update it accordingly.

You need to set `State` only when you are doing something like this

```
Students students = new Students(); //a new object which is not created using `Find`
students.name = "Heartlion";
students.address = "address text";

db.Entry(students).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: yeah u r right but my question is why where and how to use db.Entery().State=......

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        public ActionResult Edit(Students model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                using (DbAccess db = new DbAccess())
        {

                  var ID = db.students.Find(model.id);
        //db.Entry(ID).State = EntityState.Modified;
        ID.name = model.name;
        ID.address = model.address;
        ID.age = model.age;
        ID.email = model.email;
        ID.isActive = model.isActive;

        db.SaveChanges();
        }
        }

        return View(model);
        }
```